# Merging development branch after master branch has changed (committed)

Tags: git, github, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I have been working on a `development` branch for some time, meanwhile, another developer has been making changes to the `master` branch (several commits to the master).

The `master` branch now has content that I do not have in my `development` branch.

Can I merge the `development` branch without effecting the new commits in the `master` branch? i.e. not overwrite any new work in the `master`?

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the principle of merges in git is additive, you can't "overwrite" commits with a merge.

Initial situation

```
A---B---C---D <<< master
     \
      E---F <<< development <<< HEAD
```

Your coworker has made commits `C` and `D`. Let's now merge `development` into `master`.

```
git checkout master
git merge development

A---B---C---D---G <<< development, master <<< HEAD
     \         /
      E-------F
```

At this point, commits made on your `development` branch are reachable from either branch, but the commits `C` and `D` are still here.

Comment: So the content of "C" and "D" is still available after "E" and "F" have merged into "G"?

Comment: @Will Yes it is. If anything in E and F bring conflicting modifications, git will interrupt the merge process and let you handle it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you guys are working on separate aspects of the project (and depending on your IDE) you can typically specify the files you want to commit/push. I'd suggest pulling from `master` *first* and then copy over your changes and commit yours. Then create a pull request and merge the branches. It is always better to play it safe when working with git even if it takes a few more steps.

Answer (score 0):

I for one hate manually merging code. I prefer to merge master into my dev branch first.  This way, if I mess anything up, the resulting code is in my dev branch, not in master.  This also has the benefit of making the code review (which would happen before the merge took place in my case) much easier on the reviewers.

For example:

```
A---B---C---D---G <<< development, master <<< HEAD
 \          \   /
  -----E------F
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to handle this problem on your local workspace is to [rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase) your local branch. this would look like the following:

Inital State:

```
A---B---C---D <<< master
     \
      E---F <<< development <<< HEAD
```

After Rebasing your branch should look like this, if an merge conflict would occur, you will see it and can solve it locally, afterwards you can commit as usually.

```
git rebase master
A---B---C---D <<< master
             \
              E---F <<< development <<< HEAD
```

Notice that your branch is not commited yet, just up to date with the master branch.